# Parsing Error while using special characters

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I want to highlight my search string in the result set. When my search string is (Java,PHP), my code works fine.
However when my search string is (Java,C++), I am getting parsing error when the code executes this line—

```
RegExp = new Regex(Search_String.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I understand that Regex considers `+` and `–` as special characters, hence when my search string is (C++) – I used a separate regular expression as mentioned below –

```
if (Search_String.Contains("++"))
{
    RegExp = new Regex(@"C\+{2}");
}
```

I am facing issues now to combine both these Regex,so that my code works when the search string is (Java,C++). 
Can anyone suggest a resolution to this parsing error?

Code Snippet–

```
if (Search_String.Contains(","))
            {
                Search_String = Search_String.Replace(",", " ");
            }
        // Regular expression SetUp and add the Or operator.
        RegExp = new Regex(Search_String.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Highlight keywords by calling the delegate each time the keyword is found.
        return RegExp.Replace(textInfo.ToTitleCase(InputTxt), new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords));


           public string ReplaceKeyWords(Match m)
         {
             return "<span class=highlight>" + m.Value + "</span>";
         }
```

Comment: [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: When my search string is (Java.C++), what modifications I need to make to get past the below line of code --                                          // Regular expression SetUp and add the Or operator.
        RegExp = new Regex(Search_String.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Regex.Escape()`, which will escape an input string so that it's treated as literal text by a regex engine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to implement the Regex.Excape(), however I am unable to get past the parsing error. Can you please site an example for my understanding?

Comment: I used the below piece of code,but it doesnt work --              return Regex.Escape(Search_Str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim()), @"c\+\+", "${0}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

Comment: @user2619042: `Regex.Escape` escapes all special characters to make the regex engine treat them as plain text.  That includes the `|` characters.  You only want to escape the characters that you want treated as text.

Comment: Therefore, you want to escape before inserting the `|`s.

Comment: I am afraid that I am still unable to get this. Do I need to use regex.escape() while setting up the regular expression or in the return statement? Can you please give me an example which I can visualize? If my search string is (Java,C++), i want to return Java|C++

Comment: To make myself clear, the search string is (Java,C++) and I want to return (Java|C++) by setting up the regular expression and returning. The code involved is --                                      // Regular expression SetUp and add the Or operator.
        RegExp = new Regex(Search_String.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Highlight keywords by calling the delegate each time the keyword is found.
        return RegExp.Replace(textInfo.ToTitleCase(InputTxt), new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords));

Comment: @user2619042: No; you want to return `Java|C\+\+`.  `Regex.Escape()` will escape all special characters to prevent them from messing up your regex.  Therefore, you want to call it before inserting `|`, to prevent them from becoming `\|`.

Comment: Can you please help me by showing an example? I am asking because I am still getting an error while setting up the regular expression.

Comment: I used the below code as per your suggestion, but still it doesnt give me the desired output. Can ou suggest how do I return (Java|C++) -                           <string pattern;

            pattern = Regex.Escape(Search_Str) + @"+|/";
            RegExp = new Regex(pattern.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);>